# Apply by group statement in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame (df) that looks like this:

```
Patient   VisitDate    Test
   1        1mth       A
   1        2mth       A
   1        3mth       A
   1        4mth       A
   2        1mth       B
   2        2mth       B
   2        3mth       B
   2        4mth       B
   3        1mth       A
   3        2mth       A
   3        3mth       B
   3        4mth       A
```

Here is the code to make the example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Patient=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
        VisitDate=c("1mth","2mth","3mth","4mth","1mth","2mth","3mth","4mth","1mth","2mth","3mth","4mth"), 
              Test=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A","B","A"))
```

**I want to create a list of all Patients that have had different tests and what visit date that was.** How do I make this check?

Is there such a thing like an "apply by group" function?

So the **result for this example would be Patient 3 at 3mnth**  (because he took test B  and the other tests he took that the other time points was test A)

Comment: Do you only want the first occasion when they had a second type of test?

Comment: Yes, there is an "apply by group" function, and it is called, reasonably enough, `by()`. Check the help page at `?by`. You will need to think a little about the function you provide (via the `FUN` parameter), though - your question is not entirely clear to me. For instance, why wouldn't you want the output "Patient 3 at 1mth, 2mth, 4mt"? Perhaps you would like to clarify.

Comment: I want to see if there is a change in test for each patient.  I want any of the outliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some varying options:

`ave`:

```
df[as.logical(ave(as.character(df$Test),df$Patient,FUN=function(x) x != x[1] )),]

#   Patient VisitDate Test
#11       3      3mth    B
```

`by`:

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Patient, function(x) x[x$Test != x$Test[1],] ))
#  Patient VisitDate Test
#3       3      3mth    B
```

`data.table`'s `by`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, .SD[Test != Test[1]], by=Patient]

#   Patient VisitDate Test
#1:       3      3mth    B
```